# Grab the Result from Mysql, convert contents of link into XML, then output

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, xml-parsing

**UPDATED CODE**

```
  <?php
#header( "Content-Type: application/xml" );

    function doLoop($arr = array())
{
global $newsStory;
foreach( $arr as $r )
{
 //check if we're dealing with an array (multiple links)
        if ( is_array($r) === true )
        {
        //loop through the array and work with each link
        foreach ( $r as $link_)
    //check if link is an array
    if ( is_array($link_) ){doLoop($link_); continue;}
    // //end of third dimension array found
        ## gets url from database as outlined above.
        $xmlUrl = $link_;
        #Loads the url above into XML    
        $ConvertToXml = simplexml_load_file($xmlUrl);
        # -> Setup XML
        $newsStory[] = $ConvertToXml->channel->item;
        }//end of loop
        continue;//move on
 }//end of is array

        //if we get here, we know that only $r is not an array, just a value, so:
        ## gets url from database as outlined above.
        $xmlUrl = $r;
        #Loads the url above into XML    
        #$ConvertToXml = simplexml_load_file($xmlUrl);
         # -> Setup XML
        #$newsStory[] = $ConvertToXml->channel->item;
        $newsStory[] = $r;
        print_r($newsStory);



}//end of function

## Loop through results from mysql
try{
    #connection string
        // $dbconn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=thedb',array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
        $dbconn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=thedb','root','toshiba1',array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
        $q = $dbconn->prepare("SELECT FW_ArtSrcLink FROM FW_ArtSrc WHERE OneSet=1 and leagID=20");
    #call stored proc
        $q->execute();
    #get the rows into an array
        $result = $q->fetchAll();
        $newsStory = array();
doLoop($result);



    # -----> Load News Stories
        for($i = 0;$i<sizeof($newsStory); $i++){
                    //print_r($newsStory);
                    echo "<a href='".$newsStory[$i]->link."'>".$newsStory[$i]->title."</a><br />";
                    echo $newsStory[$i]->description;
                    echo '<hr>';
        }   // for()

} // try

catch(Exception $e){
    $errorPg='errors/fanwire_loop.php';
    $pageDateOfError = $e->getMessage().'on:'.'aggregate_looping.php'.' on '.date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');  # inc. details of error
    file_put_contents($errorPg,$pageDateOfError, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
} // catch


?>
```

Output of print_r():
[image: img2]

Another example of output from print_r():
[image: 6]

Comment: Aside of the code, posting your passwords on public forums is probably not a very good option.

Comment: I haven't seen your XML, but I believe you have multiple items that you should iterate over in $ConvertToXml->channel

Comment: Periklis - can you please show me how to iterate through this and what to iterate through?

Comment: Do a `print_r()` on `$result` and tell me what you get.

Comment: @navnav - this prints out an array of the 11 sets of link, desc, title like is show above. How do I ITERATE through each link. Its basically only grabbing the first item from each link. Each link has 15-20 items of (title,link,desc), but for each of the 11 links, only 1 out of the 15-20 per link are shown. I'd GREATLY APPRECIATE your help

Comment: See updated image of the output of print_r()

Comment: Ah, I see what you're trying to do. Writing answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is beginning to get really confusing.

Your code is a mess, so I'm going to start off fresh here.

You say `print_r($result)` returns this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [FW_ArtSrcLink] => http://sports.espn.go.com/espn/rss/tennis/news [0] => http://sports.espn.go.com/espn/rss/tennis/news ) [1] => Array ( [FW_ArtSrcLink] => http://sports.yahoo.com/tennis/rss.xml [0] => http://sports.yahoo.com/tennis/rss.xml ) [2] => Array ( [FW_ArtSrcLink] => http://bleacherreport.com/articles;feed?tag_id=12 [0] => http://bleacherreport.com/articles;feed?tag_id=12 )
```

So there are three arrays in that var, each containing two links.

So, two simple `foreach` loops should easily be able to deal with this:

```
foreach ($result as $value )
{

  if ( is_array($value) )
  {
     foreach ( $value as $secondValue )
     {


     }

     continue;

  }

}
```

Should be that simple.

We will have all the processing in a function.

```
function processLink( $link , $appendArr )
{

    ## gets url from database as outlined above.
    $xmlUrl = $link;
    #Loads the url above into XML    
    $ConvertToXml = simplexml_load_file($xmlUrl);
    # -> Setup XML
    $appendArr[] = $ConvertToXml->channel->item;

}
```

So, the end result should be:

```
function processLink( $link , $appendArr )
{

   ## gets url from database as outlined above.
   $xmlUrl = $link;
   #Loads the url above into XML    
   $ConvertToXml = simplexml_load_file($xmlUrl);
   # -> Setup XML
   $appendArr[] = $ConvertToXml->channel->item;

}

$dbconn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=thedb','root','toshiba1',array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
$q = $dbconn->prepare("SELECT FW_ArtSrcLink FROM FW_ArtSrc WHERE OneSet=1 and leagID=20");
$q->execute();
$result = $q->fetchAll();
$newsStory = array();

foreach ($result as $value )
{

    if ( is_array($value) )
    {
       foreach ( $value as $secondValue )
       {
          processLink($secondValue , &$newsStory);
       }

    continue;

    }

    processLink($value , &$newsStory);

}

print_r($newsStory);
```

Comment: Hey nav, this gives me an error: simplexml_load_file() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given on line 35. This line is:     $ConvertToXml = simplexml_load_file($xmlUrl); . That's weird, isn it?

Comment: Yeah, I've just taken another look at the print_r() result. It looks like the array goes in pretty deep. You're going to need a function for this. Editing answer now.

Comment: can you please look at the new code I have above. I inserted the code you gave me, but it isnt outputting anything :(

Comment: You forgot the closing curly brackets in the function. Also, you're not calling the function. You've just defined it. See my edit.

Comment: Navnav - it goes to the catch{} block, because its giving me this error: file_put_contents(errors/fanwire_loop.php) . Is something wrong with the code?

Comment: I fixed the permission error above, but now the page is blank. I literally copied and pasted your answer above..

Comment: Okay. After `doLoop($result);` do a `print_r($newsShort);` and show me the result.

Comment: I fixed the blank page. Its STILL giving the Warning: simplexml_load_file() expects parameter 1 to be string, array on the line: which is:         $ConvertToXml = simplexml_load_file($xmlUrl);

Comment: @CodeTalk I made a little edit in the code. Replace `if ( is_array($link_) ){doLoop($link_);}` with `if ( is_array($link_) ){doLoop($link_); continue;}`

Comment: Its still giving the same 'expects parameter 1' error. See my code to make sure we're on the same page please. ^^^

Comment: I read about doing a cast of the variable to a string, would that fix it?

Comment: Hmm. There is two `$ConvertToXml = simplexml_load_file($xmlUrl);` lines. Is it the first one, or the second that points to the problem line?

Comment: Okay, comment all of this out (in the second one): `$ConvertToXml = simplexml_load_file($xmlUrl);
         # -> Setup XML
        $newsStory[] = $ConvertToXml->channel->item;` and put this in: `$newsStory[] = $r;` Then do a `print_r($newsStory);` and show me the result

Comment: how do I output values of say description, title, link?